# Update JTable when mouse gets clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

I would like to create a JTable that stores mouse location when an another panel gets clicked. I have created two panels, one to display table and another to click the mouse. On click, Table doesn't get the update. Bellow is the code:

Class: TableGUI to draw Table

```
public class JTableGUI extends JPanel {
private static final int N_ROWS = 8;
private static String[] header = { "X", "Y" };
private DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null, header) {
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
    }
};

private JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
private JScrollBar vScroll = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
private int row;
private boolean isAutoScroll;

// Constructor
public JTableGUI() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Dimension d = new Dimension(320, N_ROWS * table.getRowHeight());
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(d);

    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    vScroll.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            isAutoScroll = !e.getValueIsAdjusting();
        }
    });
    this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // Extra Panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void addRow(int x, int y) {
    dtm.addRow(new Object[] { x, y });
}
}
```

Class: JPanelGUI for clickPanel

```
public class JPanelGUI {

private JTableGUI gt;
private JPanel clickPanel;
private int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 100;

public JPanelGUI() {
    clickPanel = new JPanel();
    clickPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    clickPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    clickPanel.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
}

public JPanel getPanel() {
    return clickPanel;
}


public class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        gt = new JTableGUI();
        gt.addRow(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }//Other listener methods..

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    gt = new JTableGUI();
    gt.addRow(e.getX(), e.getY());
}//
```

You can't keep creating a new instance of JTableGUI every time the mouse is clicked.

Instead you:

1. Create an instance when you create the frame and you add this instance to the frame.
2. Then you pass the reference of the JTableGUI panel as a parameter to the JPanelGUI. Then you save this parameter in the JTableGUI class and now your ActionLIstener can access this variable.